# When cloning a kvm VM with virt-clone, -ds.qcow file changes name incorrectly

Tags: kvm

When I clone with `virt-clone --connect --original vm1 --name vm2 --auto-clone` the image file `vm1.qcow` is correctly cloned and named as `vm2.qcow`, however the smaller `vm1-ds.qcow` is cloned and named as `vm1-ds-clone.qcow`. Why is that?

It's not a big problem, I can rename it manually and edit the .xml config file for the new vm to change the name there, but it's a little weird. Is this something to report to `virt-clone` repo issues or am I missing something?

Comment: --original & --name should be different afaik.   in my scripts i set VPSNAME to some new machine name https://github.com/imylomylo/make-vps/blob/master/Makefile_virt_clone18#L8

Is your `virt-clone` command correctly pasted?

Comment: Apoligies, should be `--name vm2`. Pasted incorrectly, question is still legit.